# Exciting the rotor and stator of a slip ring induction motor at different frequencies, will it develope torque?

Tags: induction-motor, speed, electric-machine, rotor-speed

I came across this question as I was preparing for an exam, I am unable to understand the theory behind it.
[image]

The textbook says the motor can run a 600 and 2400 rpm but gives no explanation. Could anyone tell me how this is, and how the rotor speeds came to be?

I think rotor will rotate with a slip where the slip frequency becomes same as the frequency as the frequency with which rotor is excited, i.e.

$$
sf = 30\text{ Hz}
$$
$$
50s = 30\text{ Hz}
$$

$$
s = \frac{3}{5}
$$

Which gives,

$$
N_{r} = N_{s} (1 - s) = 1500\left(1 - \frac{3}{5}\right) = 600\text{ rpm}
$$

Comment: counterquestion (as this is essentially just like asking a homework and presenting nothing but a guessed, incorrect answer): why do **you** think the thing rotates at 600 rpm only, and not at 2400 rpm? Maybe we can explain this based on your understanding (which might be correct, after all – the way these multiple answer choices are phrased suggests poor educational material).

Comment: That's a great start! Could you add that to your question's text? People might miss it here in the comments!

Comment: Look up doubly fed induction generator (dfig).

Comment: Well this question is more of a though experiment than a real world possibility. However it's there *for a reason* since the interaction between fields is… well everything in an IM. Also by definition it will *never* reach the stated speed (even at no load there is slip)